# After inserting a row between data I have to create a pivot table of the data above the inserted row. How do I do this as it changes week to week?

Tags: excel, vba

In my code I have inserted a row between data points where I then need to create a pivot table of the data above the inserted row. As the data will change every week, I need a code that will be able change to that data set. From there I need to perform a vlookup within the pivot table to a different workbook. How do I do this?

```
Sub ptab 
    Range(“A4:F30”).Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDataBase, SourceData:=“GL ENTERED INV raw data! R3C1:R30C6”, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:”Sheet1!R3C1”, TableName:=“PivotTable1”, defaultversion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
Sheets(“Sheet1”).Select
Cells(3,1).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(“PivotTable1”).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(“PivotTable1”).PivotFields(“Ledger acct”), “Sum of ledger acct”, xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(“PivotTable1”).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables(“PivotTable1”).PivotFields(“Amount”), “Sum of amount”, xlSum
With   ActiveSheet.PivotTables(“PivotTable1”).PivotFields(“Sum of ledger acct”)
    .Orientation = xlRowField
End with
    Windows(“cash.xlsx”).Activate
    Range(“E2”).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =“ =vlookup(RC[-3]:R[57]C[-3],’[yGL dcs.xlsx]Sheet1’!R4C1;R13C2, 2, False)”
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(“E2:E59)
End sub
```

Comment: Forgive me, I am writing this on an iPhone and for some reason it jams everything together.

Comment: To get the last row in a specified column you can use `ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I don’t see how that would help as it would find the last row in the column at the end of the data where I have inserted a row and I need to have it find that inserted row and do a pivot table everything above it.

Comment: So you could do something like put a string together "E2:E"&lastRow

Comment: So you insert the data and then ignore the new data and only make a pivot table from all the rows above it?

Comment: How would I add that too my code?

Comment: I insert data, then sort data by date and then add a column below a date I specify but then I need to do a vlookup on the data before that date I specified and all the data not in the range is left alone till the following weeks.

Comment: You have several sections of code to work, and you should work each one separately. First, the code to add new data to your existing data (you can add the new data at the end, doesn't need to be inserted - the pivot table will provide the sorting). Second, update (or delete and re-create) the pivot cache to include the new data in the range and refresh the pivot table. My suggestion is then to filter the pivot table to show only the rows with dates **before** your desired date. You don't have to create a new pivot table at all.

Comment: How would that look in code terminology?